# Android app programmatically reading from a document file while at the background

Tags: android

Is it possible to create a feature of an android app while at the background,will periodically read from a document file,such as pdf files,and sends an indicated segment of it as a notification.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, use a `Service`. It runs in the background.

From there you can send your notification. Here you have an [example](https://github.com/hannesa2/paho.mqtt.android/blob/master/serviceLibrary/src/main/java/info/mqtt/android/service/MqttService.kt)